# Two new features?

Tags: feature-request

Could there be, in the future, a Random Question link, kind of like in sites such as Wikipedia, which redirects users to a random question in Worldbuilding?

Also, could there maybe be a shorter time limit between questions?

Comment: What time limit are you referring to?

Comment: Frostfyre raises a good point. I assumed you were referring to the regular 90-minute time limit, but it's possible for users to be limited to one question a week under certain circumstances (for example, if they were question-banned, then deleted and recreated their account to try and get around it). I'm not saying that's the case here, but it's best to specify.

Comment: Welcome to meta!  It's better to ask unrelated questions separately; you can ask more than one question on meta.  Feature requests work better when they include some explanation or justification.  I doubt SE will implement a random-question link, but that sounds like something that could be done in a userscript.

Comment: The time limit was a 40-minute one that I assume is for new contributors that I encountered while trying to post that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somebody already thought of the random question link and they built it:

[Dicestack](https://www.isimonbrown.co.uk/dicestack/?site=worldbuilding&min_score=10&tagged=&answer_status=any) (also: [Stack apps page](https://stackapps.com/questions/1643/dice-stack-find-a-random-question))

As for question rate limits, that’s a completely different question but they’re in place to ensure that you don’t get yourself blocked (or rather more severely rare limited) due to too many downvoted/closed/deleted questions. The limits are pretty reasonable, since good questions usually take time to think of, write, then proofread.

Comment: Dicestack works quite well, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Could there be, in the future, a Random Question link, kind of like in sites such as Wikipedia, which redirects users to a random question in Worldbuilding?

Every question has a short link that has a number in it. You can generate your own random number and replace it in the link. I don't see how that could be useful for anyone though. If I wanted to find random questions rather than ones filtered by:

- Freshness, or
- Unanswered ones, or
- Belonging to the tags I find interesting

I'd go to less reputable sites like Quora or Yahoo! Answers.

> Also, could there maybe be a shorter time limit between questions?

The limit is there to avoid people making lots of low quality questions in a short time. Limiting the amount of what can be asked makes people put more effort into their questions.

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/221728) on the main stack exchange meta:

> Users with < 125 rep on the current site, [must wait for] 40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network (This applies to the user's IP address, not their account. If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by the other user asking a question anywhere on the network.)
>
> - Other per-site limits may apply; e.g. on Stack Overflow, new users can only ask once every 90 minutes
> - While the limit is waived for users with 125+ reputation on a given site, questions posted on sites where one has 125+ reputation still count toward the rate limit for sites where one doesn't. For instance, if you ask a question on a site where you have 150 rep, you can't ask another question on a site where you have only 100 rep for the next 40 minutes; however, you can ask them in reverse order immediately (first on the 100-rep site, then on the 150-rep site).
> - Users limited by [Anti-Recidivism System](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610), one question per week.
> - Users limited from asking questions for 1 – 7 days based on the performance of their previous questions
>     Users prevented from asking questions due to the quality filter: one question per 6 months, beginning 6 months after the ban began
> - Users with < 10k rep trip CAPTCHA* if more than once per 60 seconds, or within 5 seconds of starting new post
>     Users with ≥ 10k rep trip CAPTCHA* if more than once per 30 seconds, or within 5 seconds of starting new post
>     On Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault and Mathematics (not active on all other sites)
> - maximum of 6 questions per day
>     maximum of 50 questions per 30 days, on a rolling basis (50 questions in past 720 hours before current time).

Comment: That IP limit is odd.  What if it's a large company where a bunch of employees use SO or some other SE site that is related to the job?  New users might have to wait days to get a window to post.

Comment: @Cyn I work in such a company, this has never been a problem. I suppose if it were we'd locate the offender and kindly help them with their questions internally. What this limit does is keeping people from creating multiple accounts to circumvent a ban.

Comment: *Nodding* I was just thinking about a large tech company that might have 1000 workers, 100 of them who post somewhere on SE during working hours an average of once a week (that's 20 questions a week).  No "offenders" but just SE newbies who are having trouble finding a time when no one else has posted in the last 40 mins.